# How to play mp3 file from a different server in .NET 2.0 (c#/vb.net)?

Tags: c#, streaming, mp3, audio-streaming

I want to create a window application which will play an mp3 file, which will be on a different server.

For an example,

I have a URL (http://songs.mastemag.com/indian-movie-songs/L/download.php?get=2cdeb5bfb354f297e97ba6b6b3b53203&file=1/love-aaj-kal/01%20~%20Twist%20(MastiMag.com).mp3). I want to play this file from window application on my local machine without downloading this file.(with the help of streaming)

I have code that is using 'winmm.dll' and plays local mp3 file. Is there a way in which I can use this dll to play this kind of file.

You can also suggest me any other approach as well.

Comment: The link that you provided doesn't point to a MP3 file, it points to a web that have links to the files

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

The simple way will be to use the [Window Media Player Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa384880(VS.85).aspx) (in hidden mode).
It can work with http urls and local (file) urls.

Howto: [use it with .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/aa387148(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: I tried with this approach but it is not working. I have used Windows Media Player control and set its URL property to 'http://songs.mastemag.com/indian-movie-songs/L/download.php?get=2cdeb5bfb354f297e97ba6b6b3b53203&file=1/love-aaj-kal/01%20~%20Twist%20(MastiMag.com).mp3'. But if i click on play button it is not playing that file. 

Expected behavior should be to start buffering of that mp3 file. Am I missing to set some of the properties of player control?

Comment: I am getting en error that says 'C00D1197: Cannot play the file'

Comment: Yeah, it work for me. The URL that i was setting was not proper.